# Making pyramid using c#

Tags: c#

My question is how to make a pyramid using * and 'space' in C#? The output will be like this.

```
     *
    * *
   * * *
  * * * *
 * * * * *
```

We only need to use "for loop" for this program. I only know how to make this one.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I made a program like this:

```
static void Main(string[]args)
{
int i=o;
int j=o;

for(i=5;1>=1;i--)
  for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
   {
    Console.Write("*");
   }
  Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

I'm confused when it comes to pyramid because it includes spaces. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hard to help on this one... most help is the answer... lemme think...

Comment: anyone else jealous that he's using C# for homework?

Comment: @hunter: How so? Are you expecting him to use Assembly?

Comment: I guess `1>=1` in the `i` loop is a typo - please edit if so.

Comment: just wasn't an option for me in undergrad, that's all

Comment: +1 I recall the days I started learning programming from this question...

Comment: @sergio lawl. @yang lawl, i remember this hw assignment, good luck!

Comment: @schnaader nah, he's just going forward one way with one loop and backwards with the other

Comment: Irrespective of everything else, it would be a lot easier for you to reason about your program if you only named your variables sensibly. Try calling your loop variables `currentLine` and `currentAsterisk` (or similar) and change the magic number `5` to `height` or `totalLines`. See if that helps.

Comment: yang: think binary (spaces = 0, stars = 1). Also the size of the displayable field per line is statically 9. Only difference being that some lines have more spaces than stars. One more hint would be, think about bit masks. Hopefully I've given you enough hints! I'll see if I have time to post a proper answer (I may not).

Comment: Check this and replace line **Console.Write(" " +c);** to **Console.Write("* " );** 
[C# program to print pyramid structure](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/c-program-to-print-pyramid-structure-2.html)

Answer (score 16):

think about how you'd print the pyramid manually.

suppose 5 levels deep.

```
1st line: 4 spaces, 1 star,
2nd line: 3 spaces, star, space, star
3rd line: 2 spaces, star space star space star
```

etc.

doesn't matter whether you print spaces after the last star or not - won't make a difference to how it looks.

what do we see?

if we have a total of X levels

```
line 1: (x-1) spaces, (star space)
line 2: (x-2) spaces, (star space) twice
line 3: (x-3) spaces, (star space) three times
line 4: (x-4) spaces, (star space) four times
```

that's the pattern. I'll leave the coding to you.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, i, j, k;
            Console.Write("enter the level:");
            num=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j < num-i+1; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write(i);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this logic does not work if you provide value greater then 9

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is spaces, therefore I suggest you think about the spaces. Tell me this: how many spaces are on each row to the left of the first star? You'll likely be able to solve your own problem if you think about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to think of it as a grid or a matrix and see where you want the '*' in each row and how it relates to your loop index.

Answer (score 2):

sorry I missed this was homework... will give a strategy ... instead

it helps if you do it in notepad and think about what you are doing... you will start to understand the relationship between the line you are on and the spaces and what not...

Answer (score 2):

Post my answer after 3 hours. I think now you have almost finished it under @iluxa's advice?

```
int height = 20;
for (int level = 1; level <= height; level++)
{
    string text = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat("*", level));
    Console.WriteLine(text.PadLeft(height - level + text.Length));
}
```

I used some build-in methods e.g. `Enumerable.Repeat` and `String.PadLeft`, not the pure C-language way. The purpose is that I want to tell you since you have chosen C# as the programming language(not C/Java/etc), you should resolve problems in the C# way.

Comment: If you are writing a program like this it's for the purpose of sharping your coding logic don't use any built-in methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;               
using System.Collections.Generic;               
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

namespace pyramid_star

{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter a number:");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (int x = i; x <= n; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*"+" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Star_Pyramid
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program o = new Program();
            o.show();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        void show()
        {
           for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 9 - i / 2; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("   ");
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" * ");
                    Console.Write(" ");


                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        int num;
        Console.WriteLine("enter level");
        num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int count = 1;

        for (int lines = num; lines >= 1; lines--)
        {

            for (int spaces = lines - 1; spaces >= 1; spaces--)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");

            }
            for (int star = 1; star <= count; star++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.Write(" ");

            }
            count++;

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: the count variable simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and follow this same logic in c, c++, php, java

```
using System;

class pyramid {

      static void Main() {

           /** Pyramid stars Looking down 
               Comment this if u need only a upside pyramid **/

           int row, i, j;

           // Total number of rows
           // You can get this as users input 
           //row =  Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           row = 5;             

           // To print odd number count stars use a temp variable
           int temp;
           temp = row;

           // Number of rows to print 
           // The number of row here is 'row'
           // You can change this as users input 
           for ( j = 1 ; j <= row ; j++ ) { 

           // Printing odd numbers of stars to get 
           // Number of stars that you want to print with respect to the value of "i"?         
               for ( i = 1 ; i <= 2*temp - 1 ; i++ )
                   Console.Write("*");

           // New line after printing a row            
               Console.Write("\n");
               for ( i = 1 ; i <= j ; i++ )                
                   Console.Write(" ");

           // Reduce temp value to reduce stars count                  
               temp--;
           }

           /** Pyramid stars Looking up 
               Comment this if u need only a downside pyramid **/
           int rowx, k, l;

           // Total number of rows
           // You can get this as users input 
           // rowx =  Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           rowx = 5; 

           // To print odd number count stars use a temp variable
           int tempx;
           tempx = rowx;

           //Remove this if u use 
           Console.Write("\n");

           // Number of rows to print 
           // The number of row here is 'rowx'

           for ( l = 1 ; l <= rowx ; l++ ) {

           // Leaving spaces with respect to row
               for ( k = 1 ; k < tempx ; k++ )
                   Console.Write(" ");

           // Reduce tempx value to reduce space(" ") count  
               tempx--;

           // Printing stars 
               for ( k = 1 ; k <= 2*l - 1 ; k++ )
                   Console.Write("*"); 

           // New line after printing a row 
               Console.Write("\n");
           }           
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code might help:

```
public static void print(int no)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j <= no; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < i * 2; k++)
        {
            if(k % 2 != 0)
            {
              Console.Write("*");
            }
            else
            {
              Console.Write(" ");
            } 
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    } 
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a number pyramid:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("This is a number pyramid....");
      var rows = 5;

      for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
      {
         for(int lsc = (-rows); lsc <= -2; lsc ++)
         {
            if(lsc < (-1)*i)
            {
               //write left sided blank spaces
               Console.Write(" ");
            }
            else
            {
               //write left sided numbers
               Console.Write(-1*(lsc));
            }
         }

         for(int rsc = 1; rsc <= rows; rsc++)
         {
            //write right sided blank spaces
            Console.Write(" ");
         }
         else
         {  
            //Write sided numbers
            Console.Write(rsc);
         }
       } 
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I have described here https://utpalkumardas.wordpress.com/2018/04/20/draw-number-pyramid

Out put is:

The is a number pyramid.... 
          1
         212
      32123
   4321234
 
543212345

Answer (score 0):

I know it's javascript but might help

```
let n = 6;
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  let spaces = n-i;
  let str = '';
  for (let j=0; j < spaces; j++) {
    str+=' ';
  }
  
  for (let j=0; j < i; j++) {
    str+='* ';
  }
  console.log(str)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found two approaches:

```
       //1st approach
        int n = 6;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // need to print spaces
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            // need to print * with one space
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
            {
                Console.Write("* ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // 2nd Approach

        int rows = 6;
        int temp = 0;
        bool toggle = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2 * rows - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i < rows - temp - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (counter <= j + temp)
                    {
                        if (!toggle)
                        {
                            Console.Write("*");
                            toggle = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write(" ");
                            toggle = false;
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            temp++;
            toggle = false;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).